# Setting hyperparameters of NDT algorithm in PCL

Tags: pcl, pointcloud, perception-pcl, ros-pcl

I require some guidance on how to use PCL libraries's NDT algorithm for localisation.

The problem I am trying to solve is to monitor whether the robot is localised properly to a map generated by Gmapping (2D occupancy grid.) The robot uses a laser scanner to see the environment. The reason I went with NDT is because on looking at the working concept it looked like it's computationally less intensive than ICP for alignment. Since autoware is using it as submodule for its localisation package, I concluded that it must very robust.

I am following this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_distributions_transform.html#normal-distributions-transform). However I am not able to get proper alignment as shown in below picture. Interestingly `hasConverged()` calls also returns `true` even though it's not aligned.

- What is the purpose of `hasConverged()`?
- Are there any alignment metric one can get to know if its aligned?

Coming to the main issue, how does one set NDT parameter to get proper alignment? are there any documents to follow?

The following is my pipeline:

1. Convert map to pcl data i.e., `pcl::PointXYZ`.
2. Convert laserscan to pcl data i.e., `pcl::PointXYZ`.
3. Downsample laserscan pcl using approximate voxel sampling.
4. Apply NDT.
5. Call `hasConverged()` to check if aligned.

Code

```cpp
// approximate dynamicl voxel grid filtering
pcl::ApproximateVoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> approximate_voxel_filter;

// scan data downsampling
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr scan_keypointsPtr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr ScanPointCloudPtr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(ScanPointCloud));
approximate_voxel_filter.setLeafSize(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
approximate_voxel_filter.setInputCloud(ScanPointCloudPtr);
approximate_voxel_filter.filter(*scan_keypointsPtr);
pcl::Indices index;
pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(*scan_keypointsPtr), *scan_keypointsPtr, index);

// map data downsampling
// not performing filtering for target cloud as grid overlay is used instead of individual points.
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr map_keypointsPtr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(readmapcloud));

#ifdef visualisation
sensor_msgs::PointCloud vis_cloud3;
perceptionHelper::PCLtoROSmsg(*map_keypointsPtr, vis_cloud3);
MapKeyCloud.publish(vis_cloud3);
sensor_msgs::PointCloud vis_cloud4;
perceptionHelper::PCLtoROSmsg(*scan_keypointsPtr, vis_cloud4);
ScanKeyCloud.publish(vis_cloud4);
#endif

// perform NDT
pcl::NormalDistributionsTransform<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> ndt;
ndt.setTransformationEpsilon(0.01);
ndt.setStepSize(5.0);
ndt.setResolution(0.5);
ndt.setMaximumIterations(35);
ndt.setInputSource(scan_keypointsPtr);
ndt.setInputTarget(map_keypointsPtr);

Eigen::Matrix4f init_guess;
init_guess.setIdentity();
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr TransformedCloudPtr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>());
ndt.align(*TransformedCloudPtr, init_guess);
```

Please see below a screenshot of the RViz. Below are the colors used in this visualization:

- Yellow shows original scan cloud
- White shows map point cloud
- Red shows NDT transformed point cloud

[image]